# Connect ajax to web service in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

hello i am using a ajax with webservice to add the form information into the database :

the webservice code is :

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

and the ajax is :

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(date);
                        },
                        failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }

                    });
```

but when i run the code i get this error  :

```
GET http://localhost:53145/Group/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

can any one help me with it ? the ajax code and the webservice at the same folder and the name of it is right ?

Comment: the extention .asmx is not supported or you may route it so remove it

Comment: it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>        
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

Or change the method from `GET` to `POST`:

```
.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error clearly shows that ajax request not able to figure it out the path of webservice. I would recommend to use browser debug tool in order to sort out path issue. Just press F12 and debug mode open. For detail usage of webserivces please use below link.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1934215.aspx?Using+jQuery+ajax+to+call+asmx+webservice+methods

Comment: I saw this article but it didnt give me the solution

Comment: This article is for reference you have no issue with the code the only problem is your webservice path ?? Have you tried to use browser debug tool in order to sort it out the issue..

Comment: In browser debug tool go under network tab and see you get and post requests if your path is goodd then u get 200 ok otherwise 500 not found issue came up.